# Reference to R object inside a Latex (Sweave) document?

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I need to generate some `pdf` files containing a series of images. In each pdf file, the order of images is different. Can I have an R file with the path and name of images and to reference this object inside Latex code?
This is my Latex code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{black}
\geometry{a4paper, landscape, margin=0.15in}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat{\includegraphics{FF_0.png}}\hfill % instead of "FF_0.png" use objects[1]
\subfloat{\includegraphics{FF_0.png}}\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics{FF_0.png}}\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics{FF_0.png}}\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics{FF_0.png}}\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics{FF_0.png}}\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics{FF_0.png}}\hfill
\subfloat{\includegraphics{FF_0.png}}\hfill
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like to create an R chunk where I put an object like this `objects <- c("FF_0.png", FF_2.png, etc.)` and use inside latex code the object with indexing `objects[1]`

Could it be possible?

Comment: Is moving to RMarkdown an option ? You can write your thesis in this format.

Comment: Yes I've considered, but I think that latex has more customization like margins and so on. In this case I don't need to write a thesis but generate let's say 20 different pdfs with 20 different orders of images.

Comment: Rmarkdown uses LaTeX in the end, and much of it is exposed via options, [e.g. margin control](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#latex-options). The "killer feature" in your case are probably [parameterized reports](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html).